# rsyslog: make %syslogtag% equal length

Tags: logs, regular-expression, rsyslog

I have `rsyslog` configured to log in the following format:

```
$template long-iso,"%$NOW% %timereported:8:15%  %syslogtag% %msg%\n"
```

which produces logs like this one:

```
2013-12-14 15:59:39  postfix/pickup[4665]:  559A48C9: uid=0 from=<root>
2013-12-14 15:59:39  postfix/cleanup[5194]:  559A48C9: message
2013-12-14 15:59:39  postfix/qmgr[7358]:  559A48C9: from=<xyz@example.com>
2013-12-14 15:59:39  postfix/smtp[5196]:  559A48C9: to=<abc@example.net>
2013-12-14 15:59:39  postfix/qmgr[7358]:  559A48C9: removed
```

How can I make the text in 3rd column equal length, i.e.

```
2013-12-14 15:59:39  postfix/pickup[4665]:   559A48C9: uid=0 from=<root>
2013-12-14 15:59:39  postfix/cleanup[5194]:  559A48C9: message
2013-12-14 15:59:39  postfix/qmgr[7358]:     559A48C9: from=<xyz@example.com>
2013-12-14 15:59:39  postfix/smtp[5196]:     559A48C9: to=<abc@example.net>
2013-12-14 15:59:39  postfix/qmgr[7358]:     559A48C9: removed
```

Comment: For anyone stumbling in here, the answer is no longer valid for rsyslog: Since rsyslog 8.13.0 it's possible using the `fixedwidth` property statement. See official rsyslog documentation for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using rsyslog

I found this page titled: [Sending messages with tags larger than 32 characters](http://www.rsyslog.com/sende-messages-with-tags-larger-than-32-characters/). Within the page I noticed that you can specify what looks like a range to the fields within the template.

#### Example

```
template (name="ForwardFormat" type="string" string="<%PRI%>%TIMESTAMP:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME%
```

%syslogtag:1:32%%msg:::sp-if-no-1st-sp%%msg%")

Perhaps you could make that field wider than anything that gets displayed there, thereby forcing the output to line up?

#### Afterwards using awk

You could also do this postmortem using the following using `awk` to control the width of that 3rd column. This would be just to display the log when you want to review it, it wouldn't actually fix the issue you're asking about.

```
$  awk '{ printf("%s %s %-30s %s ", $1, $2, $3, $4); \
  for (i = 5; i <= NF; i++) printf $i; print "" }' < rsyslog.txt
```

#### Example

```
$  awk '{ printf("%s %s %-30s %s ", $1, $2, $3, $4); \
      for (i = 5; i <= NF; i++) printf $i; print "" }' < rsyslog.txt 
2013-12-14 15:59:39 postfix/pickup[4665]:          559A48C9: uid=0from=<root>
2013-12-14 15:59:39 postfix/cleanup[5194]:         559A48C9: message
2013-12-14 15:59:39 postfix/qmgr[7358]:            559A48C9: from=<xyz@example.com>
2013-12-14 15:59:39 postfix/smtp[5196]:            559A48C9: to=<abc@example.net>
2013-12-14 15:59:39 postfix/qmgr[7358]:            559A48C9: removed
```

#### Extracting just the process name without the PID

The OP asked the following follow-up question in comments.

> And do you know, by the way, how I could get rid if the part with the process ID, i.e. [4665] ? So that I only have postfix/pickup left in the 3rd column.

I believe the following method used to extract data for insertion into a MySQL database could be adapted to do what you're asking for. The thread is titled: [ProcessID empty, PID in Syslogtag](http://kb.monitorware.com/processid-empty-pid-syslogtag-t10015.html).

The important piece is in this example:

```
$template dbFormat,"insert into SystemEvents (Message, Facility, FromHost, Priority, DeviceReportedTime, ReceivedAt, InfoUnitID, SysLogTag, ProcessID) values ('%msg%', %syslogfacility%, '%HOSTNAME%', %syslogpriority%, '%timereported:::date-mysql%', '%timegenerated:::date-mysql%', %iut%, '%syslogtag:R,ERE,1,FIELD:([a-zA-Z\/]+)(\[[0-9]{1,5}\])*:--end%', '%syslogtag:R,ERE,1,BLANK:\[([0-9]{1,5})\]--end%')",sql
```

Specifically these bits. These 2 variables:

- SysLogTag
- ProcessID

Are getting populated by these formatters:

- `'%syslogtag:R,ERE,1,FIELD:([a-zA-Z\/]+)(\[[0-9]{1,5}\])*:--end%'`
- `'%syslogtag:R,ERE,1,BLANK:\[([0-9]{1,5})\]--end%'`

I believe the 1st is getting rid of the PID portion of the syslogtag output. While the 2nd is getting rid of the process name portion of the string, and keeping just the PID info.

Comment: thanks a lot. And do you know, by the way, how I could get rid if the part with the process ID, i.e. `[4665]` ? So that I only have `postfix/pickup` left in the 3rd column.

Comment: @MartinVegter - see updates.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to output fixed width fields with rsyslogd. What IS possible thou is tab-separated fields.

The following should be usable. It will also write process name and PID in separate fields:

```
$template long-iso,"%$NOW%\t%timereported:8:15%\t%programname%\t%procid%\t%msg%\n"
```

Comment: I just want to state that it's now possible (since rsyslog 8.13.0) using the `fixedwidth` property statement. See official rsyslog documentation for more info.